# How to convert Audio Blob to raw audio format in javascript

Tags: javascript, blob, google-speech-api

I have recorded audio samples from microphone and gets audio b

```
Blob(22447) {size: 22447, type: "audio/webm"}
size:22447
type:"audio/webm"
__proto__:Blob
```

Now How do i convert this blob to raw audio format and upload it to firebase storage.

Comment: What have you tried hitherto ?

Comment: I tried new Uint8Array(audioData). its saving as .raw with empty content in it